# Pass Attribute to another attribute

Tags: jsp, jstl

For example in a jsp file

i have :

```
<c:if test="${testData != null}">
${outputData = testData} // this obviously doesn't work

</c:if>
```

how can i pass the value of `testData` to `outputData`?

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where are you going to use outputData? If you want another scoped variable, then you use the c:set tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what rickz said, you have to use c:set tag to pass value of testData. Also set the type of scope you want, in this case request.

```
<c:set var="outputData" scope="request" value="${testData}"/>
```

Heres a [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_set_tag.htm).